# out of order list items in python

Tags: python, list

Assume I have a list:

```
lst = [12, 12, 12, 6, 12, 12, 1, 13, 48, 14]
```

What I want to do is to get out-of-order items. In that case, these would be:

```
[6, 1, 48]
```

The correct order of this list is increasing one: `[12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 14]` but the max increase can be by only one number. For example, in `[1, 2, 9, 3]`, `9` would be out-of-order.

What I am currently doing is:

```
for idx in range(1, len(lst)): 
    if lst[idx] < lst[idx-1]: # if item is smaller than the previous one
        print(lst[idx])

[out:] 6
       1
       14
```

How to update the code so that the output would be correct? I cannot capture numbers that are 'increasing too much', such as `48` in my example list.

Comment: Do you want the list to be globally monotonically increasing or decreasing ? Or locally ?

Comment: Ups, sorry, forgot to mention: the correct order is increasing: [12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 14]. But the max increase can be by only one number. So, 48 is out-of-order in that case.

Comment: Take the first number as the current "correct" number. Iterate over the list. If the current number is equal to the "current correct number" or +1, set it as the "current correct number". Otherwise it's out of order.

Comment: @skaistt

I suggest to add your definition of `in order` / `out of order` to your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I interpret your definition of out of order correctly, then following should do the job:

start with the first value and accept identical values or a value that is greater by one.
and add all other values to your result

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def get_ooo(lst):
    if len(lst) == 0:
        return []
    rslt = []
    prev_val = lst[0]
    for val in lst[1:]:
        if val == prev_val:
            continue
        if val == prev_val + 1:
            prev_val = val
            continue
        rslt.append(val)
    return rslt


lst = [12, 12, 12, 6, 12, 12, 1, 13, 48, 14]
print(get_ooo(lst))
```

or a slightly modified version also doing the job:

```
def get_ooo(lst):
    if len(lst) == 0:
        return []
    rslt = []
    prev_val = lst[0]
    for val in lst[1:]:
        if prev_val <= val <= prev_val + 1:
            prev_val = val
            continue
        rslt.append(val)
    return rslt
```

If you also want to know the index of the out-of-order numbers you could do something like:

```
def get_ooo(lst):
    if len(lst) == 0:
        return []
    rslt = []
    prev_val = lst[0]
    for idx, val in enumerate(lst[1:], 1):
        if prev_val <= val <= prev_val + 1:
            prev_val = val
            continue
        rslt.append((idx, val))
    return rslt
```

and you would have a list of tuples of position, value